# Formatting author affiliations - same university, different faculties

Tags: formatting, ieeetran, affiliation

I am formatting a paper using IEEEtran, and it has four authors. All authors are at the same university, but there are two different faculties. One author is appointed to both.

I made a template in Word:

[image]

How can I obtain this format in IEEEtran?

This is what I have right now:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal, but compilable example of your situation (MWE).

Comment: With which options do you load the `IEEEtran` document class?

Comment: @Mico I don't know of the different options for loading the IEEEtran class

Comment: @Vermillion - Please read the user guide of the IEEEtran document class to familiarize yourself with the available options -- and which ones might be most suitable for your purposes. (To read the user guide, open a command window and type `texdoc IEEEtran`.)

Comment: @Mico I tried looking at the options in that document, but I'm not sure how that helps with this question.

Comment: Looking at an old IEEE trans, or the user guide which is in IEEEtran format, they don't include university etc., only member status. Everything else goes in the bio section at the end

Comment: @JohnKormylo that's a good point, I might do that instead